# Refresh page to stop GIF animation loading(javascript) in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a GIF animation that will show when the form is submitted, however, when the php script is executed successfully; the gif animation won't stop... I tried to do the **include 'index.php'** however, its still not working, can you help me on how to do this?

The GIF animation function in javascript is called **ShowLoading()**

Here's my **html code:**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <linkrel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 </head>


    <script type="text/javascript">
function ShowLoading(e) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'buffer.gif';
    div.innerHTML = "<p style='color:red;'>Generating report... This might take a while..</p><br />";
    div.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; bottom: 250px; left: 35%; z-index: 5000; width: 422px; text-align: center';
    div.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    return true;
    // These 2 lines cancel form submission, so only use if needed.
   // window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
   location.reload();
}


  </script>

     <body>
      <br />

      <form method ="POST" action="/phpexcelsample/download.php" onsubmit="return checkURL();"> 




<center>  
    <div class="parent_div">  

    <p>Date From: <input type="text" class ="textbox" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo date("Ymd"); ?>" name="datepicker" readonly="True" > &emsp;  Date To:<input type="text" class ="textbox" id="datepicker1" value="<?php echo date("Ymd"); ?>" name="datepicker1" readonly="True" > </p>

            <br />
            <br />

            <input type="submit" class = "generate" name="submit" value="GENERATE REPORT" onclick="ShowLoading()" <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> > <br />

    </div>
          </center> <br />

</body>

</html>
```

Here's my **php code:**

This is a long php code that uses PHPexcel, I'm just gonna show the last few lines or the output of the **PHPExcel** including the **include 'index.php';**

```
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Result.xls"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 
$objWriter->save('php://output');

include 'index.php';
```

Comment: For one thing, your Javascript needs to be *inside* the `<head>` element, not *between* the `<head>` and the `<body>`

Comment: @FKEinternet I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: Gif file wont stop browser will keep looping the gif. Consider hiding the gif when you are done with the process.

Comment: @elegant-user hmm I didnt thought of that... wait so does that mean.. there's a code for not showing the gif image in php?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display your "loading" indicator when the `GENERATE REPORT` button on your form is clicked because `/phpexcelsample/download.php` is going to take a significant amount of time to run.  You're on the right track, but you need to get rid of these two lines:

```
e.stopPropagation();
location.reload();
```

Once the `/phpexcelsample/download.php` gets done running, it will update the browser window with the new contents, erasing the "loading" indicator.  (This is assuming `/phpexcelsample/download.php` writes the desired result page to the browser.)

Comment: I've commented out the 2 codes my result is out but the animation is still showing...

Comment: OK, now I'm confused - where is the HTML code in your question, where is the PHP code you posted, and what is `index.php`?  I assumed the PHP code was the end of your `/phpexcelsample/download.php` script, which, when it got done running, would replace the page being displayed by the browser, thus removing the "loading" GIF.

Comment: index.php contains all my html code and download.php contains the PHPexcel and all of my PHP code

Comment: Did you move your `<script>` inside of `<head>` as I suggested?